# How To Integrate Google Drive 'New' Button functionality in Google sites

Tags: google-apps-script, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-client, google-sites

Is there any way to add google drive new button functionality in google sites using any google API/Google Apps Script

[image]

Comment: You could build your own with a mix of HTML and front javascript, note that only the older version of sites supports apps scripts. And no theres not an API endpoint to add the whole button functionality all in one

Comment: is there any way to call google drive from NEW google sites using java-script ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the functions under the New button can be implemented by their corresponding Drive API equivalents. I'm not aware of a drop-in library that you can use, so afaik you'd need to write it yourself.